# Form saving data and re-submits after error

Tags: jquery, html, forms

My problem is that the form saves the data submitted after an error and if I click multiple times the submit button then it sends the data as many times

Here is the JS which handles the form. I have to note that it doesn't actually do the "submit". My problem lies in the "else" in the success callback

```
 $('#reg_form').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#error_box').hide();
    $('#error_box').html("")
    var $mail = $('#reg_email').val();
    var $usn = $('#reg_username').val();
    var $pwd = $('#reg_password').val();

data = $(this).serializeArray();

$.ajax({
    url: 'PHP/validate.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: data,
    dataType : 'json',
    success: function (dat) {
        if(dat.error==0){
            alert('user added');
        }else{
            var length = dat.error_codes.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                $('#error_box').html( $('#error_box').html() + dat.error_codes[i] + '<br/>' );
            }
            $('#error_box').show(500);
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('#error_box').hide(1500, function(){$('#error_box').html("");});  
            }, 1500);
        }
    },
    error: function(){
        alert('failure');
    }
   });
 });
```

How do I clear the data saved in the form?